# simple pro question: bind function again to an event - from the function ... kind of recoursive

Tags: javascript, jquery

if the user clicked on the certain target, then nothing should be done, but the click event should be bound "one" again - kind of recoursive ... how is this done nicely.

```
        $(document).one('click',function(ev){
            if(!$(ev.target) == $('.gallerystatus input')){
                $('.gallerystatus input').trigger('focusout');
            }
        });
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for:

```
    var clickGalleryStatus = function(ev){
        if(!$(ev.target) == $('.gallerystatus input')){
            $('.gallerystatus input').trigger('focusout');
        } else {
            $(document).one('click', clickGalleryStatus);
        }
    };

    $(document).one('click', clickGalleryStatus);
```

If `.gallerystatus input` isn't what's clicked, then it will rebind the click event.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rebinding the event if a condition does not occur it is better to unbind the event if it does:

```
var handler = function(ev){
    if(!$(ev.target) == $('.gallerystatus input')){
        $('.gallerystatus input').trigger('focusout');
        $(document).unbind('click', handler);
    }
};

$(document).bind('click', handler);
```